# My setter or constructor injection does not work

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, setter, applicationcontext

applicationContext.xml

```
  <import resource="classpath:spring/lib-ClientContext.xml"/>

 <bean id="sdpWrapper" class="com.abc.wrapper.SDPWrapper">
        <property name="aClient" ref="aClient"/>
    </bean>

<!-- this bean exists in lib-ClientContext.xml and is another project added as a maven dependency-->
    <bean id="aClient" class="com.client.AClient" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <property name="reqConfig" ref="config"/>
         -->
    </bean>
```

SDPWrapper.java

```
public class SDPWrapper extends DataTable
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SDPWrapper.class.getName());
    String response = null;
    private AClient aClient;

    public void setaClient(AClient aClient)
    {
        this.aClient = aClient;
    }

    public SDPWrapper(ReferenceDataBean r)
    {
        response = aclient.getArea(r.getId());
// aClient is always null


    }

}
```

I don't know why is the injected bean null. The aClient bean is already imported by lib-ClientContext.xml, so the declaration is redundant in applicationContext.xml. I tried both ways, still when I debug the bean in the class is null

Comment: Is the class attribute of the aClient bean in your XML a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, I changed the names of class and beans.

Comment: Shouldn't the setter name be 'setAClient' instead of 'setaClient'?